# How many Joyo (and perhaps Jinmeiyo) Kanji have only one onyomi?

Tags: kanji, readings, onyomi, jōyō-kanji

I feel this is really beneficial to have a list for in my studies. The reason is if I see an unknown word that I'm reasonably sure has onyomi readings, if the kanji in question have only one possible reading, I can automatically read the word. Score! But if there are multiple onyomi per character, I'm going to have to consider which reading applies. Single onyomi Kanji make for smooth reading and learning.

As for the multiple-onyomi Kanji, I'll be wanting more careful practice, so I'd like to know the list of them.

I could find all this out manually by looking up thousands of characters, but is this a known thing?

Comment: I don't know exactly how to go about this, but if I were in your shoes I'd reach out to someone that has an active Kanji database that you can query, and search for entries where onyomi is no more than 1. I suspect that as the user of said database you wouldn't be able to generate a query, but is it something you could probably request off the db admin somehow?

Comment: It would also depend on how the database is organized -- at Wiktionary, for instance, if a kanji has the same _kan'on_ and _goon_, that reading is often listed twice -- once for each category.  Still query-able, but you'd need to structure the query differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The number of Joyo kanji with only one **Joyo** ON-YOMI is 1789 characters.

On [this](https://www.kanjidatabase.com/index.php) useful kanji database website, you can query Joyo kanji for various criteria. In the '*Select Kanji from Database*' section ([here](https://www.kanjidatabase.com/kanji_database.php)), I performed a query where `# of On = 1`, together with what the ON-YOMI is and what the translation is.

The results of that query can be seen here: [JOYO KANJI ONE JOYO ON-YOMI](https://pastebin.com/6a9e5Jpd).

My answer does not address the issue of including Jinmeiyo kanji.

***EDIT:*** This is a list of Joyo kanji that have only one Joyo ON-YOMI reading, but they may have non-Joyo ON-YOMI readings.

Comment: Just to clarify, this appears to be a query of jouyou kanji that only have one jouyou onyomi, right? They may have non-jouyou readings. For instance, 衣 is on the list, but it has both the jouyou reading of い and the non-jouyou reading of え (as seen in the word 浄衣). I'm not sure if that meets the criteria imagined by the OP or not.

Comment: That's a good point and I omitted the non-Joyo readings since the OP seemed concerned with Joyo. But I will edit the answer to clarify.

Comment: This is a very, very helpful answer. Thank you. I will look into this site and try to learn how to use it for future inquiries (though it seems a little technical). The good news is that there are far fewer multi-onyomi Kanji than I thought. That helps.

Comment: @dozy_boy Indeed, most kanji have only one Joyo on-yomi. Personally, I always found the kun-yomi more troublesome because many of them have multiple readings which are important to know and are difficult to remember how to read.

Comment: @dozy_boy how do you define "non-common use" ?

Comment: @kandyman Sorry, I read my comment again and deleted it because it was really unclear. I mean, are there readings for Joyo Kanji which are officially "non-joyo" by the Japanese government. I want to understand what Leebo was referring to.

Comment: Yes there are readings which fall outside the Joyo "curriculum". Usually they are readings which are not as common as others. But sometimes they can be important too. You could experiment with the " Acc. Freq. Kun with Proper Nouns" - putting high values like 50,000 - 55,000 will give you very common Joyo Kun readings.

Comment: For example, for the kanji 止, the Joyo kun-yomi is と, as in 止める(とめる). But there is a non-Joyo kun-yomi や, as in 止める(やめる).

Comment: Outside of the curriculum. That makes sense; that they wouldn't study technically true but rare readings. In those cases, I likely wouldn't bother studying that type of reading either until I happened to encounter it naturally. It's a shame that the website doesn't account for them directly as a filter, but that's a minor point. My question is still overwhelming answered.

Comment: @dozy_boy You can include non-Joyo readings in the output by checking "Reading beyond Joyo". There are other functions which can give you information on non-joyo readings too. I suggest experiment with it and reading the accompanying manual https://www.kanjidatabase.com/manual.php